# How do I exclude or negate two queries?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am new to SQL, so this is probably very simple, however, I wasn't able to find the solution.

Basically my query is as follows:

```
SELECT UserID
FROM Users

NOT UNION

SELECT UserID
FROM User_Groups
WHERE GroupID = '$_[0]'
```

However, I am not sure what the syntax is to exclude one query from another.
What I am trying to say is give me all the user ID's *except* for those that are in group X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT UserID FROM Users
  WHERE UserID NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM User_Groups WHERE GroupID = ?)
```

P.S. Don't interpolate variables into your queries as this can lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities in your code. Use placeholders instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Users.UserID
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN User_Groups ON Users.UserID = User_Groups.UserID
WHERE Users.GroupID = '$_[0]'
AND User_Groups.UserID IS NULL
```

You can left join to the other table and then put an IS NULL check on the other table in you WHERE clause as I've shown.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`EXCEPT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-EXCEPT) as well:

```
SELECT UserID
FROM Users
    EXCEPT
SELECT UserID
FROM User_Groups
WHERE GroupID = '$_[0]'
```

`EXCEPT` is SQL's version of set subtraction. Which of the various approaches (`EXCEPT`, `NOT IN`, ...) you should use depends, as usual, on your specific circumstances, what your database supports, and which one works best for you.

And eugene y has already mentioned the SQL injection issue with your code so I'll just consider that covered.

I linked to the PostgreSQL documentation even though this isn't a PostgreSQL question because the PostgreSQL documentation is quite good. SQLite does support [`EXCEPT`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html):

> The EXCEPT operator returns the subset of rows returned by the left SELECT that are not also returned by the right-hand SELECT. Duplicate rows are removed from the results of INTERSECT and EXCEPT operators before the result set is returned.

Answer (score 1):

NOT IN() - Negating IN()

`SELECT UserID FROM User_Groups WHERE GroupID NOT IN('1','2')`

The IN() parameter can also be a sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a solution to be used with a postgres or a mySQL database?
Or are you looking for a plain SQL solution?

With postgres a subquery with "WHERE NOT EXISTS" might work like:

SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME)
WHERE
(NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME)